# How to make a section of a background image a clickable link

Tags: imagemap

I've been trying to make a section of a background image clickable with an external link. I've tried a few suggestions using 'imagemap' tag from archived inquires here but had no luck. I'm guessing this is due to the fact that the background image is set in CSS and the nature of the website.

I have only basic coding knowledge, so it's a trial and error approach for me which is very time consuming and I've run out of trials now.

Below is the image of the page. The area 'HERE' (under 'Book Now') should be the clickable area.

[Screenshot background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5nhJ.jpg)

```
CSS

body {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
font-weight: 600;
font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
background: url(../images/bg_2019_2.jpg) center 0 no-repeat #000 fixed;
background-size: cover;
color: #636363;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1.2em;
}

HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.athleticum.co.uk"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.athleticum.co.uk/images/section2_bg.jpg"/>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Athelticum® - Training for Body and Brain."/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="Spinning® and functional equipment training." />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="693292167509917"/>  

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ATHLETICUM® – Training For Body And Brain</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/icons/css/animation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/icons/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.athleticum.co.uk/favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- First Screen -->
<section class="screen-section section-1">
    <div class="section-inner">
        <header id="site-header">
            <!-- To change site subtitle just write any text between <h3>...</h3> -->
            <h3 id="site-subtitle"></h3>
        </header>

        <footer id="site-footer">
            <ul id="site-social">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/SpinningUKandIreland/" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_facebook_square">         
                </i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/SpinningUK_IRE" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_twitter_square"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/spinningukandireland" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_instagram_square"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="scrolldown">
                <span class="keyscroll">
                    <span class="scrolldown-title">Use Up &amp; Down Keys</span>
                    <span class="key-up"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></span>
                    <span class="key-down"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span>
                </span>
                <span class="label-or">or</span>
                <span class="mousescroll">
                    <span class="scrolldown-title">Scroll down</span>
                    <i class="scroll-icon"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: could you add show the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
height: 100%;
width:1646px;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
font-weight: 600;
font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5nhJ.jpg') center 0 no-repeat #000 fixed;
background-size: cover;
color: #636363;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1.2em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5nhJ.jpg" width="1646px" height="auto" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
<area target="_self" alt="Book Now" title="Book Now" href="www.athleticum.co.uk" coords="1544,1241,2032,1393" shape="rect">
</map>

</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.athleticum.co.uk"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.athleticum.co.uk/images/section2_bg.jpg"/>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Athelticum® - Training for Body and Brain."/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="Spinning® and functional equipment training." />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="693292167509917"/>  

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ATHLETICUM® – Training For Body And Brain</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/icons/css/animation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/icons/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.athleticum.co.uk/favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- First Screen -->
<section class="screen-section section-1">
    <div class="section-inner">
        <header id="site-header">
            <!-- To change site subtitle just write any text between <h3>...</h3> -->
            <h3 id="site-subtitle"></h3>
        </header>

        <footer id="site-footer">
            <ul id="site-social">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/SpinningUKandIreland/" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_facebook_square">         
                </i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/SpinningUK_IRE" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_twitter_square"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/spinningukandireland" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_instagram_square"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="scrolldown">
                <span class="keyscroll">
                    <span class="scrolldown-title">Use Up &amp; Down Keys</span>
                    <span class="key-up"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></span>
                    <span class="key-down"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span>
                </span>
                <span class="label-or">or</span>
                <span class="mousescroll">
                    <span class="scrolldown-title">Scroll down</span>
                    <i class="scroll-icon"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm considering  your image height and width is 100% 100% , if you have any specific width and height for image then please share that

Comment: Thanks. The link area link works; but now the background picture is an additional page on the fan scroll. Should be on the original background pictures. That is the huge hiccup. Background image dimensions seem to be 1646x789.

URL: www.athleticum.co.uk

Comment: can you elaborate more? Unable to get you

Comment: whatever understood from you I have updated previous answer try it out

Comment: Thanks, Amit. Really appreciate your help.

You need to visit the site to see what I mean: www.athleticum.co.uk
(This is the actual site that I'm updating; just so you can see what I mean by 'fan' element.)

The background picture is static. Your solution creates an additional 'fan' element with the background picture and the link; but I would like to have the link area on the static background image.

Comment: You can't use a background image for an image map.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
height: 100%;
width:1646px;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
font-weight: 600;
font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5nhJ.jpg') center 0 no-repeat #000 fixed;
background-size: cover;
color: #636363;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1.2em;
}
.booknow{
background-color:green; /* remove this property once you set the position and uncomment below to make it transparent*/
/*background-color:transperant;*/
position:relative;
left:200px;
top:250px;
width:180px;
height:65px;
display:inline-block;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.athleticum.co.uk"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.athleticum.co.uk/images/section2_bg.jpg"/>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Athelticum® - Training for Body and Brain."/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="Spinning® and functional equipment training." />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="693292167509917"/>  

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ATHLETICUM® – Training For Body And Brain</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/icons/css/animation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/icons/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.athleticum.co.uk/favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>

    <!-- First Screen -->
<section class="screen-section section-1">

    <div class="section-inner">
        <header id="site-header">
            <!-- To change site subtitle just write any text between <h3>...</h3> -->
            <h3 id="site-subtitle"></h3>
        </header>

        <footer id="site-footer">
            <ul id="site-social">
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/SpinningUKandIreland/" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_facebook_square">         
                </i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/SpinningUK_IRE" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_twitter_square"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/spinningukandireland" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social_instagram_square"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="scrolldown">
                <span class="keyscroll">
                    <span class="scrolldown-title">Use Up &amp; Down Keys</span>
                    <span class="key-up"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></span>
                    <span class="key-down"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></span>
                </span>
                <span class="label-or">or</span>
                <span class="mousescroll">
                    <span class="scrolldown-title">Scroll down</span>
                    <i class="scroll-icon"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="booknow" onclick="location.href='www.athleticum.co.uk'">Book now</span>
            </div>

        </footer>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: add new span tag and make it transparent , place that span over your image "Book Now" button . and use JavaScript  onclick="location.href='www.athleticum.co.uk'"

Comment: This is what I managed to get with your suggestions:

[link] http://athleticum.co.uk/2019/index_1.html

You mentioned that it is not possible to use the background image for an image map. I'm guessing that's why the image map is appearing in the scroll icon section. 

Anyway, the section is now visible in green but the background picture has now been scaled up and is not in the original size anymore - don't know why this happened. If the positioning of the image area will eventually mess up the layout, I will have to abandon this and find a completely different solution.